# Django: Return foreign key's custom field value substitute for id number in filter()

Tags: django, filter, foreign-keys

I have below models.py

```
class site(models.Model):
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    site_description = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.site_name

class asset(models.Model):
    STAT_CHOICES = (('Available', 'Available'), ('Deployed', 'Deployed'), ('Down', 'Down'))
    asset_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STAT_CHOICES, max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    site = models.ForeignKey(it_asset_site)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.asset_id
```

As we known, table “site” would create site_id as PK by default.
After i imported data into table "asset", In the django's admin, the "site" is display  "site_name". That effect is come by "def **unicode**(self):".
So i want to get the same effect for

```
f = asset.objects.filter(site__site_name__contains='NNG1')
```

But in the "f", "site" field display the number(site_id) not the NNG1(site_name), the sample:

```
b = f.filter(site__site_name__contains='NNG1')
In [44]: b.values()[0]
Out[44]: 
{'asset_id': u'3914100271',
 'owner': u'',
 'status': None,
 'site_id': 8L,*****<-now*****
 'notes': u'',
}
```

Had a way to make the filter result become:

```
{'asset_id': u'3914100271',
 'owner': u'',
 'status': None,
 'site_name': u'NNG1',*****<-hope*****
 'notes': u'',
}
```

like the django admin page show?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify fields as parameters in `values()`:

```
b.values('asset_id', 'owner', 'status', 'site__name', 'notes')[0]
```

Comment: Cool, it works!! I'm lost in variety docs and forgot to try "__" in values() .:( 
Big thanks!